# How to find the mean residence time for a continuous time Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a finite Markov chain $X(t)$ with a known generator $Q$.

What is the mean time for the Markov chain to stay at a given state $i$?

Is the mean time to stay at $i$ just the reciprocal of $-Q_{i,i}$ ?

Can you please point to a reference.

Comment: Do you mean before the first jump, or averaged over the chain running for a long time? For the first jump, yes, it is $-\frac{1}{q_{ii}}$, understood as $+\infty$ if $q_{ii}=0$. This is not difficult to prove, but it is sufficiently basic in the subject that we need to know your exact definitions in order to know how to formulate a proof.

Comment: I mean the expected value of the residence time before the next jump

Comment: Yes, that is equal to $-\frac{1}{q_{ii}}$. If you'll give your precise definition of a CTMC then I can prove it.